# Home screen, main window, start screen or something else?

Tags: word-usage, computing

Could you please help me to find the right term for a starting (home, main) window or screen of the programme, i.e. when one launches a program on a PC or Mac and starts it, a ... window (or screen opens)? 
Thank you.

P.S. Below is the sample of the window. It is the main window where users do the most of the work. Often it has an application menu (file, view, edit, about, etc). Here a user can click on "file" for example and open this menu item.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you refer to the window would depend on which aspects of it you want to emphasize:

- If you want to emphasize the fact that this window is the first one that opens when the application is launched, **starting window** could be appropriate (or **start screen** in the case of a full screen application).
- If you want to emphasize the fact that this is the window where the user spends most of their time and attention, **main window** sounds good.
- If you want to emphasize the fact that this window is the starting or base point for other things the user will be doing (possibly in other windows), **home window** seems appropriate.
- If you want to emphasize the specific functionality of the window, you can consider a name that adds information regarding what the window is used for. For example:

  - **file explorer**
  - **file explorer window**
  - **document window**
  - **project window**
  - **project browser window**
  - **data entry window**
  - etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the first screen that (normally) greets you when you launch a desktop application, it's commonly called a [*splash screen*](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/splashsc.htm) (see also [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)).

Comment: Thank you, I got it, but it's not that exactly.